# Docker on Windows: how to run multiple websites (LAMP stack)?

Tags: php, windows, apache, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a local environment for web development (LAMP stack) using  Docker.

All websites live in folder called Sites with this structure:

```
/Sites
   -- site1.local
      -- www
   -- site2.local
      -- www
```

For every website I need its own version of PHP and MySQL.

So far I was able to run one local website with this `docker-compose.yml` (uses `php:7.1-apache`):

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: 'sp-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: 'sp-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sp-demo
      MYSQL_USER: sp-demo
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: sp-demo
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'rb-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
  redis:
    container_name: 'rb-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

The website is available at `http://localhost:80`

Questions:

1) How do I make it accesible by domain domain, for example, `http://site1.local` instead of `http://localhost:80`? I heard I need some Nginx Proxy for this (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), but I can't understand how to set it up with Apache in my case.

2) How to set up the second website (`http://site2.local`) the same way to run it simultaneously? As far as I understand, I would need to change all ports (80, 443 and 3306), otherwise I will have a conflict when I run `docker-compose up -d`? Is it possible without changing ports?

Thanks for the answers!